# Debugging run time error of armadillo package

Tags: c++, debugging, rcpp, armadillo

I am using armadillo c++ library for developing a Rcpp package. However I am finding debugging any run time errors from armadillo extremely cumbersome. Currently I have to insert printout after every line to fish out line at which errors are coming. Armadillo just throw errors like:

```
error: subtraction: incompatible matrix dimensions: 756x1 and 26x1
```

and it does not tell any information about line number. Using gdb is also not particularly helpful because the error might be coming after many iterations. Is there any better to get line number of where the error is occurring.

Comment: What do you expect? A psychic reading your code for you?  Debugging can be hard, and template libraries do not make it easier.  Such is life.

Comment: Thanks Dirk for comments. I just meant is there some variables ( like pre-processor)  that can be setup so that slightly more informative error-msg (such a line number ) is thrown.

Comment: I find [these debug macros](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html) to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I like the gcc facilities too and we could expand [these](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/macros/debug.h) if need be.

Comment: To solve this problem I put __line__ and __debug__ with traceback in debug.hpp of armadillo. However, this is not ideal way of debugging it. RcppArmadillo become impossible to debug for a larger code. The only other way is to printout after every single line (that really was not option as my code had thousand of lines). I hope RcppArmadillo developers add basic line and file information on assert error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the Rcpp integration, but I debug my Armadillo code using gdb.

Just make sure that you never catch any exceptions like `std::logic_error` in your code. If you then run the program from within gdb, it will abort once the error occurs and just by typing `bt` you get a nice back trace that shows you which line is to blame. And then you also easily inspect variable values etc. in that stack frame.

You do not need to step through the code to make use of the advantages of the debugger.

If Rcpp does not allow avoiding to catch that exception, you should always be able to write a simple C++ test program for your code that does not block the debugger.